# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string with Halo API

Tags: php

So I have this following code:

```
    <?PHP

    $remote_url = 'https://www.haloapi.com/stats/h5/players/PLAYER/matches';

    // Create a stream
    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header' => "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: MY SUBSCRIPTION KEY")                 
      );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    $file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

    print(json_decode($file));

    ?>
```

and it gives me the following error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\HaloAPItest\index.php on line 17

What do I do?

Comment: You're looking for `print_r()`, not `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

What Darren said in his comment. print_r handles variables of any class. print just strings.

Another useful function is var_dump. It's also good to write a function to do it like var_dump_pre and make it put 
`<pre> </pre>` 
tags around the output. That formats it nicely on screen.

Comment: Thank you, so if I just use echo or print it should work? I used var_dump and it said it was a string, and then it still printed out the loooong string

Comment: @ImInThatCorner correct, if it's a string print will work. If it's not a string print and echo will either error or just print out the type. It's always more beneficial to use var_dump or a least print_r so you can print any object and don't have to worry about the type.

You also need to check that the file_get_contents function returns a successful value and not a failed result file_get_contents:"The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure."